# Why do we obtain two points when we equate the derivative of the bottom half of a circle centered at $(0,0)$ to -2?

Tags: calculus

Given $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and tasked to find the points where the derivative is -2, we can differentiate implicitly to reach $2x+2yy' = 0 \Rightarrow y' = -\frac{x}{y} = -2 \Rightarrow x=2y$

Inserting into the first equation gives us $4y^2 + y^2 = 1 \Rightarrow y = \pm \frac{\sqrt5}{5} \Rightarrow x = \pm \frac{2 \sqrt{5}}{5}$.

We do expect two points, but one from each of two different functions: $$y = \pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$$

If we take one of them, say $y = -\sqrt{1-x^2}$, we have $y' = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, which is also $y' = -x/y$ as in the implicit differentiation, and when we equate $y'$ to -2 we still get two points even though we are dealing with just half of the circle: $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = -2 \Rightarrow x = -2\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
At this point we square both sides. **I think the truth of the matter with regards to my doubts is what does it do to the calculation to square both sides here because what we end up with is two points as solutions to this bottom half of the circle instead of one point only.**

Why do we get two points when we deal with just the half of the circle?

Comment: Which two values of $x$ satisfy $x=-2\sqrt{1-x^2}?$ (Hint, only one will, but there will be two solutions after you square both sides.)

Comment: Indeed, I am aware that only one of the solutions is the correct one for the bottom half of the circle, you just have to plug the values in to check. My question is what is the intuitive interpretation of why squaring takes you to a common step between solving for the top half and bottom half solutions?

Comment: If you have an equation $u=v$ and you square both sides, then $u^2=v^2,$ which is true for $u=v$ or $u=-v.$ So any solution to $u^2=v^2$ is either a solution to $u=v$ or $u=-v.$

Answer (score 2):

Squaring both sides of an equation tends to introduce *extraneous solutions*.  That's solutions which are not solutions to the original equation.

You got the two solutions from $x^2=4 (1-x^2)\iff x=\pm\dfrac2 {\sqrt5} $.

But when you plug in  $\dfrac 2{\sqrt5} $, you get $\dfrac 2{\sqrt5} =-2\sqrt {1-4/5} $, or $\dfrac 2{\sqrt5}= -\dfrac 2{\sqrt5} $.  Thus it is not a solution.

---

As far as *intuition*, the basic phenomenon is $x=2\implies x^2=4$, but not the converse.

Answer (score 0):

There are *two* points where the slope is -2.

This is also confirmed by the *quadratic equation* appearing and supplying the *two* roots... shown in figure below drawn to scale.

[image]

Extra roots are concomitant when raising power of variable. If we square x=1, x=-1 also  enters  as a solution. If we cube x=1 and try to solve $x^3=1,$ two additional complex roots also sneak in.

Comment: Yes there are two roots when the entire circle is considered. The question was: why do both roots appear when we are looking at the function representing only one half of the circle.

Comment: Whether you look at it or not the circle and its slope *exists in all the four quadrants*. Your general equation already provided a passport to let in all allowable solutions to enter conveniently. Consider the situation when you were looking into the third quadrant situation at start. First quadrant root will automatically  get in.